# I built a simple game in Javascript but I don't know how can I add an end to it

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first question on this website. I built a simple game by Javascript but I don't know how can I add an end to it, Because I am a beginner. Thanks for helping me.

```js
document.getElementById("start").onclick =function() { 
    function getRandomColor() {
      var letters='0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
      var color='#';
      for (var i=0; i <6; i++ ) {
       color += letters[Math.round(Math.random()*15)];
      }
      return color;
     }


    var time; var createdTime; var clickTime; var reactionTime;
    function makeBox() {
     time=Math.random();
     time=time*1000;
     setTimeout(function(){
      createdTime=Date.now();
      if (Math.random()>0.5) {
       document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius="100px"
      } else {
       document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius="0"
      }
      var top=Math.random(); 
      top=top*300
      var left=Math.random();
      left=left*300
      document.getElementById("box").style.top=top+"px";
      document.getElementById("box").style.left=left+"px";

      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor=getRandomColor();
      document.getElementById("box").style.display="block"
     },time);
     
    }
    document.getElementById("box").onclick =function() {
     clickedTime=Date.now();
     reactionTime=(clickedTime-createdTime)/10;
     reactionTime=Math.round(reactionTime);
     reactionTime=reactionTime/100
     document.getElementById("resulte").innerHTML =reactionTime;
     this.style.display="none";
     makeBox();
    }
    makeBox();
   }
```

Tanks for helping me.

Comment: You keep calling makeBox(), on you #box onclick,  Take this out and it will stop,.  btw. It wasn't very hard to make your snippet into a working snippet.  If you can do a working snippet it's much better.

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry Mr @Keith , I didn't understand "snippet"

Comment: Sure Mr @MartinGottweis. https://jsfiddle.net/8mp0tckg/4/

Comment: Yes Mr @Aks I want to create an end function but I don't know how can I do that.

Comment: Simplest would be to count the clicks and after user clicks five times end the game. Instead of the alert you can create a nice message with average response time. https://jsfiddle.net/8mp0tckg/5/ Good job though.

Comment: @AbuAtaa : Then Martin have a point. You can also create a button "Stop game"

Comment: Oh, thank you so much Mr @MartinGottweis. That's what I am looking for.

Comment: Thank you Mr @Aks.

Comment: A snippet is pretty much the same as a fiddle, but a snippet is better as it's built into Stack Overflow, and it's also not an external link that could disappear.  I'll put @MartinGottweis as an answer, he could then copy mine, you accept his, and then I'll delete mine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is MartinCothweis answer as a snippet..  Like I say it's not harder than using a Fiddle but much better in the long run..

If Martin copies this, and you can then accept his answer.

> Simplest would be to count the clicks and after user clicks five times end the game. Instead of the alert you can create a nice message with average response time. jsfiddle.net/8mp0tckg/5 Good job though.

```js
var clicked = 0

document.getElementById("start").onclick = function() { 
 function getRandomColor() {
  var letters='0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color='#';
  for (var i=0; i <6; i++ ) {
   color += letters[Math.round(Math.random()*15)];
  }
  return color;
 }


 var time; var createdTime; var clickTime; var reactionTime;
 function makeBox() {
  time=Math.random();
  time=time*1000;
  setTimeout(function(){
   createdTime=Date.now();
   if (Math.random()>0.5) {
    document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius="100px"
   } else {
    document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius="0"
   }
   var top=Math.random(); 
   top=top*300
   var left=Math.random();
   left=left*300
   document.getElementById("box").style.top=top+"px";
   document.getElementById("box").style.left=left+"px";

   document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor=getRandomColor();
   document.getElementById("box").style.display="block"
  },time);
  
 }
 document.getElementById("box").onclick =function() {
  clickedTime=Date.now();
  reactionTime=(clickedTime-createdTime)/10;
  reactionTime=Math.round(reactionTime);
  reactionTime=reactionTime/100
  document.getElementById("resulte").innerHTML =reactionTime;
  this.style.display="none";
  clicked++
  
  if (clicked >= 5) {
   alert('good game!')
  } else {
   makeBox(); 
  }
 }
 makeBox();
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #FAEEC6;
   }
   #box {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
   }
   #text {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 40px;
   }
   #bold {
    font-weight: bold;
```

```html
<h1>Test your reaction!</h1>
  <p>click on boxes and circles as quickly as you can!</p>
  <button id="start"><b>start !</b></button>
  <p id="bold">Your time: <span id="resulte">0</span>s</p>
  <div id="box"></div>
```